# Get rows that are present in one dataframe, but not the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to extract those rows from `df1` which are not existent in `df2` (identity is the index). For the below example, I would expect the first row in `df1` to be returned. Unfortunately, the result is empty.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'level-0': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
    'level-1': ['s2', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's2'],
    'level-2': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
    'level-3': ['19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
    'level-4': ['HRB', 'HRB', 'HRB', 'HRB', 'HRB', 'HRB'],
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
})

df1 = df1.set_index(['level-0', 'level-1', 'level-2', 'level-3', 'level-4'], drop=False)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'level-0': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'],
    'level-1': ['s2', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's2', 's2'],
    'level-2': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
    'level-3': ['19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
    'level-4': ['HRB', 'HRB', 'HRB', 'HRB', 'HRB', 'HRB']
})
df2 = df2.set_index(['level-0', 'level-1', 'level-2', 'level-3', 'level-4'], drop=False)

# all indices that are in df1 but not in df2
df_unknown = df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
print df_unknown
```

What's wrong with the selection?

**Update**

I figured out what went wrong. The dataframes were read from an Excel file and some Series were interpreted as `int`, while the dataframe to compare with had its columns already converted to `str`. This resulted in different indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_index` is not in place by default, so `df1` and `df2` still have their numeric index after the call. Do either

```
df2.set_index(..., inplace=True)
```

or

```
df2 = df2.set_index(...)
```

You will see that by far the most methods in pandas work that way.

Comment: Strange. I have `df = df.set_index()` in my actual code and got it wrong in the minimal example. Not sure why the actual code doesn't work...