# Pandas getting all rows listed in one dataframe but not the other UNORDERD

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I cannot find an easy way to get all the rows of a data frame that are found in one dataframe but not a second dataframe if the data is unordered.

These two answers talk are solutions for ordered data:

> [Get rows that are present in one dataframe, but not the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946391/get-rows-that-are-present-in-one-dataframe-but-not-the-other)
>
> [pandas get rows which are NOT in other dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe)

So just to make it clear I'm trying to get this:
[image: data from one dataframe thats not found in the other dataframe]

In one of those related question mentioned above I found a multiindexing solution that supposedly works with unordered data, but I was unable to implement it. I am hoping theres an easier way.

let me give you an example of the data I'm working with:

```
DF1
col_a   col_b
1325    foo
1397    foo        #<---matching value, but not matching index in DF2
1645    foo
...     ...

DF2
col_1   col_2
1397    foo        #<---matching value, but not matching index in DF1
1500    foo
1621    foo
...     ...
```

Now if that were all the data in both dataframes the result for processing this specifically for DF1 would look like this:

```
DF1_UNIQUE
col_a   col_b
1325    foo
1645    foo
```

(So I'm really only caring about `col_a` or for DF2 `col_1`). Notice its missing the 1397 row. that's because it is found in DF2, so I don't want it returned to my new DF. But its not found in the same index and there in lies the problem I have. I already easily created a solution if all the matching indexes are lined up, but I don't know where to start on the indexes that aren't lined up. Can I use the merge function? Or is that the wrong tool for this job?

This code isn't entirely relevant but its the solution I came up with if all the indexes lined up correctly:

```
def getUniqueEntries(df1, df2):
    """takes two dataframes, returns a dataframe that is comprized of all the rows unique to the first dataframe."""
    d1columns = df1.columns
    d2columns = df2.columns
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=d1columns[0], right_on=d2columns[0])
    print(df3)
    return df1[(~df1[d1columns[0]].isin(df3[d1columns[0]]))]     

def main(fileread1, fileread2, writeprefix):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(fileread1)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(fileread2)

    df3 = getUniqueEntries(df1, df2)
    df4 = getUniqueEntries(df2, df1)
    
    print(df3)
    print(df4)

    df3.to_csv(writeprefix+fileread1, index=False)
    df4.to_csv(writeprefix+fileread2, index=False)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use merge with the `indicator` parameter:

I renamed the columns to avoid duplicated columns You can also pass `left_on` and `right_on`

```
merged = DF1.merge(DF2.rename(columns={'col_1': 'col_a', 'col_2': 'col_b'}), how='left', indicator=True)
merged
Out: 
   col_a col_b     _merge
0   1325   foo  left_only
1   1397   foo       both
2   1645   foo  left_only
```

Now, you can filter `merged` using the indicator column:

```
merged[merged['_merge']=='left_only']
Out: 
   col_a col_b     _merge
0   1325   foo  left_only
2   1645   foo  left_only
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `indicator` parameter

Comment: thanks everyone who answered! This answer is the easiest for me to understand, I'm 1-day new to pandas, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

This uses boolean indexing to locate all of the rows in `df1` where the values in `col_a` are NOT (`~`) in `col_a` of `df2`.  It uses [`isin()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to locate matching rows, and the negation operator (`~`) to find the opposite of those (i.e. the ones that don't match).

```
df1[~df1.col_a.isin(df2.col_a)]
```

You mentioned an index, but your sample data does not have one.  The matching is thus done only on the values in `col_a` per your example.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but isn't the `isin` matching the same indexes between the two columns? I was under that impression.

Comment: I may have implemented it wrong, but this solution didn't work. it returned the entire list, and didn't detect any matches (I believe this is due to the fact that all the matches are in different indexes, as I have mentioned).

Comment: Could you provide a better sample of your dataframe?  e.g. `df1.to_dict('list')` You mention an index, but your sample does not have one. Also, is it possible to have the same value in `col_a` but different values in `col_b`? If so, how do you want to handle that?

Answer (score 3):

here is a pandas equivalent for SQL (Oracle's) minus operation:

```
select col1, col2 from tab1
minus
select col1, col2 from tab2
```

in Pandas:

```
In [59]: df1[~df1.isin(pd.DataFrame(df2.values, columns=df1.columns).to_dict('l')).all(1)]
Out[59]:
   col_a col_b
0   1325   foo
2   1645   foo
```

Explanation:

```
In [60]: pd.DataFrame(df2.values, columns=df1.columns)
Out[60]:
  col_a col_b
0  1397   foo
1  1500   foo
2  1621   foo

In [61]: pd.DataFrame(df2.values, columns=df1.columns).to_dict('l')
Out[61]: {'col_a': [1397, 1500, 1621], 'col_b': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo']}

In [62]: df1.isin(pd.DataFrame(df2.values, columns=df1.columns).to_dict('l'))
Out[62]:
   col_a col_b
0  False  True
1   True  True
2  False  True

In [63]: df1.isin(pd.DataFrame(df2.values, columns=df1.columns).to_dict('l')).all(1)
Out[63]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```